# How to create a certificate from CSR and key with Java

Tags: java, digital-signature

I am exploring about digital certificates using Java. But I can't find how to create a certificate from CSR and key. Could you help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a Certificate Authority (CA)? Because it's the CA who generates the certificate from the CSR. Have you tried something and have some code to share? Are you just looking for pointers or want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: thank you, the problem is i have generated key and csr from java code and now i want to generate certificate from csr and that key

Comment: I found the answer here: https://gist.github.com/vivekkr12/c74f7ee08593a8c606ed96f4b62a208a